# To reign is worth ambition

Tags: word-usage, usage

**be worth something** can be used as--

> The Taj Mahal is worth **a** visit.
>   
>   The idea is worth **our** attention.

In this kind of sentences either an article or a determiner is used after **worth** . But in the sentence.

> To reign is worth ambition.

No article or determiner is used. Is it correct?
I think it must be

> To reign is worth an ambition.

Comment: I don't really understand *either* form of the sentence. If I had to pick something to go before *ambition* I would make it *our*. (The act of reigning is something worthy of us spending our ambition on.) But almost nobody ever gets the choice of reigning—so it's not a phrase that would normally ever be used . . .

Comment: I found it in wren and martins book

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you found it, if the meaning isn't clear. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambition is generally a non-count noun, so the determiner "a" would normally be incorrect.

That said, the meaning of "To reign is worth ambition" is very unclear. It looks very dated and, indeed, Wren and Martin is a book from the 1930s. Many of its examples are old fashioned, or express attitudes typical of British Imperial Army officers, which may seem odd today.

It probably means "It is okay to be ambitious, because then you could become a leader".  That is odd to modern attitudes.

Comment: To reign is infinitive and it acts as the subject of the sentence.

Comment: I know. It is just the attitude expressed in the sentence is so odd to modern people, that the meaning is hard to grasp.

Comment: @jk ambition is countable noun also